# cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') when using Fetch API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I want to fetch some products from api, the issue is that the template will not wait for the async function to run and for the `products` prop to be filled with data fetched, as its an async function, so the value of `products` will be null when the template runs and `products.value` will give error `cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`, so i used `v-if` to check if there are products before trying to display them, but it displays nothing, as it doesn't catch the change been made to `products` prop after getting the data, in `react` with `useEffect api` i could pass an array of dependencies and sepicify `products` state to make the update happens, what is the equivalent in `vue` ? thanks in advance

```
Route::get('/products',function(){
    $products = DB::table('products')->get()->toArray();
    return response()->json([
        'products' => $products,
    ]);
});
```

```
import { ref, watchEffect } from "vue";

const products = ref(null);

watchEffect(() => {
    fetch("/products")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => (products.value = data));
});

<template>
  <div v-if="products">
   <ul v-for="product in products.value">
    <li class="py-4 px-2">
     <Link href="...">
      <img :src="product.imageUrl"/>
       <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
     </Link>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `<ul v-for="product in products">`.

Refs are unwrapped automatically in templates. So initially you are trying to get `(null).value`.

Also you don't need `watchEffect()` (there's no reactive dependencies inside it), just do the fetch in the component's root.

I also suggest to avoid using refs for non-primitives. That way you can avoid unwrapping refs in the script secion.

You can also omit `<div v-if="products">` since initially `products` is an empty array:

```
import { reactive, onMounted } from "vue";

const products = reactive([]);

onMounted(async () => products.push(...await(await fetch("/products")).json()));

<template>
   <ul v-for="product in products">
    <li class="py-4 px-2">
     <Link href="...">
      <img :src="product.imageUrl"/>
       <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
     </Link>
    </li>
   </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: It's correct, but asynchronous side effect in setup results in SSR-unfriendly code, onMounted() is a better place for it

Comment: didn't work, i did this : ```onMounted(() => {
    (async () => products.push(...(await (await fetch("/products")).json())))();
    console.log(products);
});```, it gives me error ```Spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function```, and ```console.log(products);``` returns empty array

Comment: your solution is 100% correct, the problem was the way i return these products from the server is not the correct way